# How to cell values as new columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
    Labels
1   Nail_Polish,Nails
2   Nail_Polish,Nails
3   Foot_Care,Targeted_Body_Care
4   Foot_Care,Targeted_Body_Care,Skin_Care
```

I want to generate the following matrix:

```
    Nail_Polish   Nails   Foot_Care   Targeted_Body_Care   Skin_Care
1       1           1         0                0               0
2       1           1         0                0               0
3       0           0         1                1               0
4       0           0         1                1               1
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df2 = df['Labels'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')
```

The resulting output:

```
   Foot_Care  Nail_Polish  Nails  Skin_Care  Targeted_Body_Care
1          0            1      1          0                   0
2          0            1      1          0                   0
3          1            0      0          0                   1
4          1            0      0          1                   1
```

Comment: If I have another new row:
    5  Foot_Care, Nails

How can I add it to the matrix?

Comment: Ideally you'd wait until you have all the rows you need, then do it all at once.  If that's not possible, use the same procedure as above with the new rows, then use `concat`, and possibly `fillna(0)`, to combine the old and new rows.